# Show no table error after the resetting the simulator on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios-simulator

My iOS app uses Master Detail view controller with sqlite3 database, it was working fine before i reset the iOS simulator.Now its shows me 'No such table error' can anyone help me, It'd be very great.

Comment: voting down? what happen ?

Comment: Check whether database exists with specific table in document folder ?

Comment: i had check it in xcode and it was working fine and then i had  to reset my simulator and now app is running fine but it gives" NO Table" error  and I am unable to fetch or load data from sqlite database

Comment: after resetting simulator check database wherther table exists or not.

Comment: i did check it in sqlite3 manager its still show the same error .....how do i fix it please  help to fix it my whole project is stuck because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below URLS for Sqlite Database 
http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm

May be the problem is in your database creation at Document directory